# Slack API , Slash commands not updating

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am building a custom Slack app. I am noticing a behavior that seems odd.

If a user installs the App they have available to them the slash commands bundled with the app. If I change or add slash commands to the app the user does not see the modified or changed slash commands unless they 'uninstall' and 'reinstall' the app.

How can I update my app without requiring users to reinstall?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to Slack support, a user will always need to reauthorize new functionality so, the will need to reinstall.